# Google Map is not working in Ionic Application

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am learning Ionic right now and I am trying to create a map module in my project but it shows nothing when I click the maps.html from the side-bar and I think I've some problems with library issues. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**maps.js**

```
<ion-view title="Maps" id="page4">
<ion-content overflow-scroll="true" padding="true" class="has-header" ng-controller="MapController">
 <div id="map" data-tap-disabled="true"></div>
</ion-content>
```

**index.html**

```
 <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[mykeynumber]&sensor=true"></script>
```

**style.css**

```
.scroll {
    height: 100%;
}

#map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**app.js**

```
foo.controller('MapController', function($scope, $ionicLoading) {


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.3000, -120.4833);

    var mapOptions = {
        center: myLatlng,
        zoom: 16,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
        map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));
        var myLocation = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude),
            map: map,
            title: "My Location"
        });
    });

    $scope.map = map;
});


});
```

[I'm getting a blank Map page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIOSU.png)

Comment: https://market.ionic.io/plugins/locateme   go through this

Comment: Still I didn't solve my problem because I can see the map in index.html but I want to see the map in map.html. I didn't understand why I got an error like this.

Comment: Your code works just fine. Do you get any errors in console? Are you seeing the map on browser but not on mobile or what is the problem, can you elaborate a little?

Comment: Actually I didn't get any errors but when I run the code both google chrome and my android device, it shows a blank page. I added a screenshot for the problem

Comment: When I tried your code it worked fine for me. So it must be something else that is affecting it in your app. Have you checked from inspect that the map renders or not? If it's only a problem of it not displaying correctly even if it's rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this link, its working

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=en"></script>
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/AI2QajduyvUdeCcYJGHO?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks for your demo app it solved my problem and how can I set the cursor in a specific postion and direct the user to that location in this code demo ? Thank you for your time by the way

Answer (score 0):

I implement the demo and it worked. Also it works when I click the "view on google maps" part on the browser. I can direct the user to a special location in browser in a new tab but when I run on my android device "view on google maps" is not clickable. I simply want to direct to user through google maps application in android. Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.